# Resize DIV to for one page scroll website

Tags: html, css, resize

I don't even know if what I am asking is possible, but it's worth a shot.  Basically I have a one page scrolling website controlled by jQuery, but it's a very very simple code, no plugin or external doc. That works great.

Every "page" if you will is divided into different divs to separately control function of pictures, tables, fonts, etc. per each page. Like this:

```
//home page
<div id="home">
content here
</div>
//about page
<div id="about">
content here
</div>
```

and so on and so forth... my question is, can i do something like this? I've tried but maybe I don't have the "decimal" in the right spot...

```
//home page
<div id="home resize">
<div id="home">
content here
</div>
</div>
//about page
<div id="about resize">
<div id="about">
content here
</div>
</div>
```

and then CSS be

```
home resize {
position: relative;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things I see right away. First, your CSS rule should be `.home.resize` instead of `home resize`. Second, height, when using percentages, requires that the height be set on the html tag to make a difference. So you will need rules such as this:

```
html {
    min-height: 100%;
}

.home.resize {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Otherwise, height will never take up the entire browser window height.

This all being said, I would guess that your best solution would involve JS or jQuery in some way. I know there are several single page scrolling plugins that do this job quite well.

Answer (score 0):

First things first. HTML id's cannot contain spaces. You should define a class name resize. That being said. You can achieve this by using this.

Here is a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/magnus16/HPLVz/)**

```
div id="home" class="resize">
  content here
</div>
<div id="about"  class="resize">
  content here
</div>
```

---

```
    .resize{
    display:block;
    height:100vh;
    margin:0;
}

#home{
    background-color:red;
}
#about{
    background-color:blue;
}
```

vh is viewport height. It will set the height of your div same as viewport. 1vh is equivalent to 1/100th of viewport height